# how to get target of an angular event?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. I just want to manipulate the DOM of the target of an event. As you can see, I'm mashing some jquery in there.

How does angular give me the DOM object so I can manipulate its relatives? i.e. what are the valid properties of ev? I would have thought that ev.target or ev.currentTarget gave me the DOM object.

```
<div class="table-cell">
  <a ng-mouseover="rollover(this)">Go<div class="tip">Tooltip</div></a>
</div>

$scope.rollover = function(ev){
  $(ev).parents('.table-cell').css('overflow','visible');
  $(ev).find('.tip').show();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-mouseover="rollover(this)"`

this keyword refers to scope. You need to pass $event in your rollover function then use $event.target.

```
<a ng-mouseover="rollover($event)">Go<div class="tip">Tooltip</div></a>
```

But you should create directive if you want to manipulate DOM.

```
<a my-dir>Go<div class="tip">Tooltip</div></a>

app.directive("myDir", function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).on("mouseover", function () {
            $(element).parents('.table-cell').css("background-color", "yellow");
            $(element).find('.tip').toggle();
        });
    }
  };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z3of0sko/)**

Comment: I see. Thank you. 

Wow that was surprisingly tough to solve.
I guess because I'm not doing it the angular way, using a directive.

(In fact, I can probably simply use bootstrap's tooltip, if I could get it to work...)